# Do I need a single entry of multiple Schengen visa travelling from Austria-Croatia-Switzerland-Austria)

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, israeli-citizens

I will arrive Austria from Tel Aviv in August as a tourist, stay there for a couple of days, then take the train from Vienna to Zagreb, stay for a couple of days in Croatia the take a train from Zagreb to Zurich, 3days there and back to Vienna as my exit point back to Tel Aviv.
My questions is, do I need to apply for multiple entry or single entry Schengen Visa since I will enter and left Austria to non-Schengen country and enter again from a Schengen country?

Comment: Is it correct to assume you hold Israeli passport?

Comment: you will need a multiple entry visa to enter Switzerland

Comment: As an Israeli citizen you're not required to obtain a Schengen Visa: http://www.greekembassy.org/embassy/content/en/Article.aspx?office=11&folder=79&article=20405

Comment: As a matter of fact you're not required to obtain a visa for Croatia either: http://www.mvep.hr/en/diplomatic-directory/visa/